# Which version of Ubuntu for Toshiba NB500?

Tags: versions

Can Toshiba NB500 (1024 MB DDR2, Atom 1,66 GHz - pseudo 64bit) cope with Ubuntu 14.04? If not, which version of Ubuntu can I use, if I want to work comfortably? I would like to use Unity if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with Xubuntu or Lubuntu, both will run just fine on your hardware. You could give Ubuntu a whirl, but don't expect lightning speed.

As for versions, I would definitely stick with the latest (or the latest LTS), which is 14.04.

Comment: Thanks :) I should choose 64 or 32-bit version?